# Is there a way to track Google Sheets user email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet and I want to filter users view based on their email address. I'm not sure how to filter their email since Sheets doesn't provide a function for that. Basically, I want something like:

> if (email = johnsmith@gmail.com, show row 1 AND hide all others, do nothing)

I've tried Googling for it, but the only results yield sending emails through sheets, not seeing what email is viewing the sheet. Is there a way to do this? Maybe using Apps Script?

For example, John Smith would see:

| Viewer | Email Address |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | j.smith@yourmail.com |

| Check |
| --- |
| =if (B2 = j.smith@yourmail.com, Sheet1!A2 = "J. Smith ID", "") |

| Person | ID |
| --- | --- |
| John Smith | 1234 |

But Bob Patel would see:
| Viewer | Email Address |
|:-----------|-----:|
| Bob Patel |b.patel@yourmail.com |

| Check |
| --- |
| =if (B2 = b.patel@yourmail.com, Sheet1!A2 = "B. Patel ID", "") |

| Person | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Bob Patel | 5678 |

Comment: How about trying create a filter in data menu?

Comment: You can also do it google apps script but I'd need to have a table of the data sheet.  Also not I don't follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: Filtering data by email is something I've tried already. It isn't possible to filter by email.

Comment: Do you think you could explain how I could do it in apps script?

Comment: `I want to filter users view` How are you filtering this? Using a basic [filter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681)? Are you aware that you cannot hide some rows for a user and not for another user? Either a row is hidden or it is not, it doesn't depend on which user is viewing the sheet.

Comment: Yes I know, I was wondering if there was a way I could change this by using apps script or data studio.

Comment: While you can retrieve the active user's email via [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()), this could only work if there was never more than 1 user accessing the spreadsheet at the same time. Is that the case? Otherwise, what you want to do is not possible, for the reasons I mentioned in my last comment (for example, while user #1 is seeing the spreadsheet, user #2 opens it and the filter criteria changes according to user #2, even for user #1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Log the email address of the person running the script.
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
```

Try [getActiverUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

Comment: Would this be for apps script?

Comment: Yes this is apps script

Comment: Do you know how I would incorporate it with my spreadsheet though?

Comment: I need more information about what you trying to accomplish.  If you could provide the sheet data in a table and possibly a [mcve]

Comment: I edited the question to provide a visual representation of what I basically want.

Comment: Can you provide a table to show how your data is organized so that I can determine where to get the `id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230055/discussion-between-daniel-tam-and-cooper).

Comment: I realize I never told you that I decided not to continue this project since it does not seem easy to do. Thank you for all your help!